# MATLAB Optimization - how to move on to next possible solution if a condition is not satisfied?

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I am using the fmincon optimization to find parameters that fit constraints. It is currently set up like:

```
constraints = [1 2 3];    
interval = 100;

time_start = [2500];
time_boundary = [500 5000];
param2_start = [0.5];
param2_boundary = [0 1];

opts = optimset(optimset('fmincon'),'TolFun',1e-4,'TolX',1e-4,'display','iter');
[x,fval] = fmincon(@(X) func(X,constraints,interval),[time_start param2_start],[],[],[],[],[time_boundary(1) param2_boundary(1)],[time_boundary(2) param2_boundary(2)],[],opts)
```

where a simplified `func` is:

```
function out = func(X,constraints,interval)

  time = X(1);
  param2 = X(2);

  % Check inputs before calculations
  if (mod(time,interval) > 0)
      out = 999;
  else
      % Perform calculations based on parameters, constraints and interval.
      % Simplified to:
      out = time/interval;
  end

end
```

However, the function (`func`) can fail if `time` is not integer-divisible by `interval`.

Is there a way to catch this within the function so that `fmincon` moves onto another solution without failing?

Or, is there a better way to use `fmincon` (or another optimization tool) to avoid this issue?

Comment: what is `time`? can you add a [mcve]? What do you mean by divisible? Integer-divisible? All real numbers are divisible among themselves.

Comment: Apologies. I tried to simplify for a minimal example, but made it too simple. Yes, I mean integer-divisible. I have modified the problem description.

Comment: @user3743235 your example still doesn't run....

Comment: No, you need an MINLP solver for this.

Comment: @houtanb Modified again. This should now at least work, even if it is a poor example of using such optimization.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Could you please expand on your comment?

Comment: Fmincon is for continuous problems. Your problem has some discrete structure, so fmincon is not suited. Minlp solvers allow integer variables to be present in nonlinear optimization problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, modify your function to something like (pseudo-code because you have not provided the contents of your function)

```
function(X, constraints, interval)
try
   <<code that can fail when function is being optimized>>
   <<time/interval when interval == 0 for example>>
catch
   return <<penalty value>>
end
end
```

Basically, the idea would be that when the function fails, you would return a penalty value so that the minimizer would move away from the values it passed to your function.

---

Edit: Based on your edit, the function would be:

```
function out = func(X, constraints, interval)
try
    out = X(1)/interval;
catch
    out = 1e10;
end
end
```

However, you will never end up in the catch portion of the block because the division will never cause an error, even if `interval` is `NaN`, `Inf`, or `0`. I am only posting this because you asked me to. My understanding of a function "failing" is specifically that it throws an error. If it simply produces an incorrect result, then your function above is correct. I would just modify `out` in the failing case to be higher than any value you would obtain otherwise to train the minimizer to move away from this spot.

Comment: I like this idea, however I'm still unsure how best to do this. Could you please update this answer based on my revised question? Can I simple do: `function(X, constraints, interval); try; mod(time,interval) > 0; catch; return; end; % Perform calculations based on parameters, constraints and interval; end` ?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. However, if do `catch; return; end` then fmincon produces the error **Output argument "out" (and maybe others) not assigned during call..** as it returns without assigning `out`. If I instead do `catch; out = 1e10; return; end` then fmincon finishes: **Optimization completed because at the initial point, the objective function is non-decreasing in feasible directions to within the selected value of the optimality tolerance, and constraints are satisfied to within the selected value of the constraint tolerance.** Do I need to adjust the stopping criteria or something else?

Comment: Yes, you need to adjust the value assigned to `out` to work with your project. Usually when minimizers get an unexpectedly large function value, they'll penalize the input values they tried and try something else, moving away from these input values. If `1e10` is way too large for your data, try something else.